# quantmod - getQuote() not working for tickers on different exchanges

Tags: r, quantmod

I am going through the `quantmod`-`getQuote()` to find a solution to the problem I am running into [(link)](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/blob/master/R/getQuote.R).

When I run the following;

```
metrics <- yahooQF(c("Name", "Volume", "P/E Ratio", "Dividend Yield", "Shares Outstanding"))
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT")
stats <- getQuote(symbols2, what = metrics)
```

I am able to obtain some yahoo finance statistics on `GOOG` and `MSFT`. However when I add the symbol `3888.HK` to the list I obtain an error.

```
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT", "3888.HK")
stats <- getQuote(symbols2, what = metrics)
```

Error message:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
In addition: Warning message:
In getQuote.yahoo(Symbols = c("GOOG", "MSFT", "3888.HK"), what = list( :
  symbols have different timezones; converting to local time
```

Does anybody know of a work around for this, I cannot seem to find what to change in the `getQuote()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the dot in the ticker name. You actually found a bug in the function.

If you run `getQuote("3888.HK", what = metrics)` you get a result:

```
                 Trade Time     Name  Volume P/E Ratio Dividend Yield Shares Outstanding
3888.HK 2018-09-20 16:08:17 KINGSOFT 5549058  4.991025    0.000952381         1365229952
```

The issue is the different timezone. And if the tickers per timezone are unequal you will get an error.

This works:

```
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT", "0005.HK", "3888.HK")
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT", "0005.HK", "3888.HK", "FAGR.BR", "AGFB.BR")
```

this doesn't

```
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT", "FB", "0005.HK", "3888.HK")
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT", "0005.HK", "3888.HK", "FAGR.AB")
```

The problem is in this part of the function:

```
 Qposix <- sapply(split(sq, sq$exchangeTimezoneName), convertTZ)
```

This returns a list instead of a vector of timezones. And if the number of stocks in per stock exchange are not equal you will get this error. Adjusting this is simple, but needs a change in the quantmod package. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/246) on github.

The workaround for now is to run your code per exchange instead of a big list of tickers in one go.

**edit:** added github issue.

Comment: What I am currently doing is something like the following: `USstocks <- c("HP", "HMI", "IBM", "MSFT", "NTES", "NOK", "CRM", "TCEHY", "TWTR", "WB")

KSstocks <- c("003550.KS", "005930.KS")

CNstocks <- c("ZTE.CN")` to separate the exchanges. Then to get the quotes separately

`HKstats <- getQuote(HKstocks, what = metrics)

USstats <- getQuote(USstocks, what = metrics)

CNstats <- getQuote(CNstocks, what = metrics)` Then just join all the data together using `rbind()` - Seems to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I think the error occurred as you have 2 counters from the NASDAQ but only one counter from the HK Exchange (e.g. "arguments imply differing number of rows" error).

When I tried to get the financials of two counters from NASDAQ and two counters from HK Exchange, the problem gets resolved:

```
metrics <- yahooQF(c("Name", "Volume", "P/E Ratio", "Dividend Yield", "Shares Outstanding"))
symbols2 <- c("GOOG", "MSFT", "0005.HK", "3888.HK")
stats <- getQuote(symbols2, what = metrics)

Warning message:
In getQuote.yahoo(Symbols = c("GOOG", "MSFT", "0005.HK", "3888.HK" :
  symbols have different timezones; converting to local time

stats
             Trade Time                  Name   Volume P/E Ratio Dividend Yield Shares Outstanding
GOOG    2018-09-20 04:00:01         Alphabet Inc.  1077192 50.576115             NA          349883008
MSFT    2018-09-20 04:00:01 Microsoft Corporation 18559784 52.441310    0.014839678         7668219904
0005.HK 2018-09-20 16:08:17         HSBC HOLDINGS 15168181 18.303152    0.007505519        19422699520
3888.HK 2018-09-20 16:08:17              KINGSOFT  5549058  4.991025    0.000952381         1365229952
```

Another alternative is you could obtain the financial information by exchange; you do not have to get all counters from all exchanges you are interested in concurrently. Meaning, you could do something like the following:

```
US_symbols <- c("GOOG", "MSFT")
HK_symbols <- c("0005.HK", "3888.HK")

US_stats <- getQuote(US_symbols, what = metrics)
HK_stats <- getQuote(HK_symbols, what = metrics)

US_stats
          Trade Time                  Name  Volume P/E Ratio Dividend Yield Shares Outstanding
GOOG 2018-09-20 09:39:47         Alphabet Inc.   91776  50.93889             NA          349883008
MSFT 2018-09-20 09:40:07 Microsoft Corporation 1956869  52.62911     0.01504029         7668219904

HK_stats
             Trade Time          Name   Volume P/E Ratio Dividend Yield Shares Outstanding
0005.HK 2018-09-20 16:08:17 HSBC HOLDINGS 15168181 18.303152    0.007505519        19422699520
3888.HK 2018-09-20 16:08:17      KINGSOFT  5549058  4.991025    0.000952381         1365229952
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right I have just added equal number of tickers and I am able to retrieve the data.  Which is great but I have unequal tickers from about 3/4 different exchanges. Perhaps I will need to make sure all the exchanges has an equal number of firms.

Comment: May you elaborate on "Another alternative is you could obtain the financial information by exchange".